# is there anything such as bootstrap in Rails like we have bootstrap.groovy in grails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table of roles ,

I need to insert a few entries to the table when the application is executed .

In Grails we have bootstrap.groovy to perform tasks whenever the application is executed .

is there anything such in Rails also .

I want to insert rows in to tables , when the application starts on the server ,

as far as I know twitter bootstrap will not help ,

any suggestion would be deeply appreciated .

well i am a newbie to Rails , so let me know if there is anything such or if twitter bootrap can be used for this also

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap is about bootstrapping your user-interface, not the application development.

If you'd like to perform tasks:

- One time, or on demand: rake tasks ([overview](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial) & [rails rake](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake))
- Each time the application is started: [rails initializers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)